# Web scraping links within table with BeautifulSoup returns NoneType and empty table using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to web scrape all of the Form N-MFP2 and then open the link to web scrape the information within the form. However, I am stuck at retrieving the form. I tried multiple methods of web scraping, including beautifulSoup and selenium, but the returned  is empty and I could not go further to get the row data. Appreciate any help because I've been working on this problem for over 3 hours.

My code is as follows:

```
# Create an URL object
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=843781'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') # it does not work even with "lxml"
# Obtain information from tag <table>
table = soup.find("table", id="filingsTable")
```

The webpage: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=843781

[The table screenshot is here; Form N-MFP2 is highlighted as red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Zt0.png)

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` doesn't execute JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

That table is rendered dynamically. You can access the data source from the json file. Once you have that, it's simply just pulling out the accessionNumber and then creating the approriate url to get to the link.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Create an URL object
cik = 843781
cik_padded = f'{cik:010}'
url = f'https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK{cik_padded}.json'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['filings']['recent'])

nmfp2 = df[df['form'] == 'N-MFP2']
```

[image]

Not sure what you want from the linked page, but once you get the relevant data to create the url, you can start getting the linked data page. Note: the link to the document is in there too...so if that's what you are after, you can use that instead. But like I said, don't know what you wanted from here.

```
for idx, row in nmfp2.iterrows():
    accessionNumber = row['accessionNumber']
    accessionNumber_alt = ''.join(accessionNumber.split('-'))
    url = f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/{cik_padded}/{accessionNumber_alt}/{accessionNumber}-index.htm'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)    
    dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)
    
    print('\n')
    for table in dfs:
        print(table)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's quite helpful. Can you explain the code "jsonData['filings']['recent']"? What do the first ["fillings"] and second parameters ["recent"] indicate and where did you get ["recent"]? I am not that familiar with JSON.

Comment: JSON (what you would see in python as dictionaries and lists) is basically structured as key:value pairs (and the values can also be key:value pairs..so a nested json structure). You get those values by calling on those keys. See the image example I added above). `recent` is just a key to data we were after